# Why is lineHeight of UIFont larger than font size?

Tags: ios, fonts

I use the code below to calculate the number of lines of string with limited width.

```
NSString *text = @"abcdefgh";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
CGFloat h = [text suggestHeightWithFont:font width:320.0];
NSInteger lines = (h > font.lineHeight) ? h/font.lineHeight+1 : h/font.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"height %f, %f, number lines:%ld", h, font.lineHeight, (unsigned long)lines);
```

But I found that `font.lineHeight` (log shows it is 17.900391) is larger than the font size which is set as `15.0`.

The log message shows:

> height 17.900391, 17.900391, number lines:1

Comment: http://www.zsiegel.com/2012/10/23/Core-Text-Calculating-line-heights/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### lineHeight = a font's ascender (part of a letter that is above)
                  + a font's descender (so below baseline)
                  + a font's leading (vertical spacing)

e.g. for font size 10
A might have ascender=10, descender=0
g might have ascender=5, descender=4

lineHeight = 14 + leading ... 14,5 maybe

---

Note that the numbers here were random and only given to better illustrate the issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link.

Comment: I found that a font's descender is negative.

Comment: The leading of iOS's system font is 0, which is strange.